# Magento2 Shipping help need

Tags: magento2

Magento Experts, I need a Shipping implement but I don't understand how can I do this. Site source country Sweden. Shipping requirements below--

### United States

Standard: $12 – 2-5 working days (Free over $450).

Express: $30 – 1-3 working days

### European Union

Standard: €10 – 2-5 working days (Free over €350).

Express: €22 – 1-3 working days

### United Kingdom

Standard: £9 – 2-5 working days (Free over £305).

Express: £20 – 1-3 working days

### Sweden

PostNord: 65 SEK – 1-3 working days (Free over 1500 SEK)

### Rest of the world

Standard: €14 – 3-7 working days (Free over €350).

Express: €30 – 2-4 working days

Please give me a good suggestion.

Thanks.

Comment: Is it Magento 1.9 or 2 because the answer will be different.

Comment: You can use webshopapps matrixrate where you can manage it.

Comment: It is Magento 2